# How to find keyframe in MPEG-2 stream, packed in MPEG-TS

Tags: video, video-streaming, keyframe

I've written MPEG-TS demuxer. It unpacks transport stream to PES packets.
Now I want to drop all frames till I meet keyframe.

How can I do it? Should I find for Sequence block in each PES frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to look for a set Random Access Indicator bit in the [MPEG-TS adaptation field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream#Important_elements_of_a_transport_stream).  If you are dealing with a transport stream that does not use [RAI bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=%22Random%20Access%20indicator%22&title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&advancedSearch-current=%7B%22namespaces%22%3A%5B0%5D%7D&ns0=1), you'll need to rely on information in the contained elementary stream.  For example, if you are processing an H.264 stream, you'll need to look for [IDR slice NAL units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Abstraction_Layer#Coded_Video_Sequences) (type 5).

Comment: Does MPEG-TS or MPEG-PES provide any fields to locate the next SPS (sequence parameter set) or IDR slice NAL unit, or should the media player scan the H.264 elementary stream for the start code prefix and NAL unit type until it finds them?